# Closing a connection in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, database-connection, derby

In Apache Derby, stored procedures are java methods. In those methods, I'm acquiring the connection using the following:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection");
```

Should this be closed once we have finished using it?

Answer (score 0):

No, typically it should not be closed in your stored procedure code.

The whole point of this type of connection, which the [Derby documentation](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/devguide/cdevspecial29620.html) calls a "nested connection", is that it re-uses the same transaction as the statement that causes it to be run.

Closing the connection would mean that the invoking statement would have confusing behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Just following up on this - there doesn't seem to be ill effects caused by closing the connection. In fact, some Derby examples online close the connection as well. That said, it's not being used in any transaction.